# How to make sure that async function is loaded before Widget build?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a screen with some informations about the user.

In my build widget I have this:

```
Column
 (
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>
    [
    Text('User Points', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
    Text('${this.user.points}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 34.0))
    ],
 ),
```

And I have a function to update the dashboard each time user access it.

```
void updateDashboard() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var api_key = prefs.getString('api_key');
    var userID = prefs.getInt('userID');

    var res = await http.post(('http://myApp.com/getDashboardPreferences/'+userID.toString() + '/' + api_key),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json"
        });

    this.user = User.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));

    setState(() {
      if (res.statusCode == 200) { 
        this.user.setPoints(this.user.points);
      } else {
        print("Something is wrong");
      }
    });

  }
```

And in initstate I call that function:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    updateDashboard();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This works, but however, I get that `${this.user.points}` is `null` for a few seconds (I get that warning screen) and then it is loaded and everything is fine. I guess it is because my function is `async`... But how can I assure that this `updateDashboard()` is called before rendering `Widget build()` ?

Comment: Look at `FutureBuilder`. This is a convenience widget that allows you to build a mock screen (e.g. centered circular progress indicator) until the future completes, when you instead build the whole screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use `FutureBuilder` then you can do something like

```
if(done)
    Column(  /* whatever */ )
else
    Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
```

```
void updateDashboard() async{
    /* whatever */

     if (res.statusCode == 200) { 
        setState(() {
           this.user.setPoints(this.user.points);

           done = true;

      });          
 }
```

```
@override
  void initState() {
    /* whatever */
    done = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, async means that the data might take time to load and is handed off to another thread to load. There can be multiple non blocking ways to do this:

1. Provide a default value for the `user` object, so by the time the async method finishes, you show proxy/default values and `setState()` makes sure the new value gets displayed when loaded.
2. This method requires you to load widgets conditionally, i.e load `Text` widget when there's data else load a `Container()`.

Example for the second approach:

```
this.user!=null?Text('${this.user.points}'):Container()
```

This way you don't need to show the widget till the value loads. Either of the approaches work and depending on your use-case, you can choose which you can apply.

Comment: Tried your solution but without success :( ... Is there a way to put "Loading... " screen until everything is loaded in build?

Comment: This is just a shorthand to writing if/else. I think you should go with the accepted answer, it does the normal one.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the function right before the return widget.

Comment: that doesn't make a difference. The widget will still load before the function is finished. Doc's answer works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loading variable like `bool _loading` then anywhere you start `loading` you `async` function you can `setState` of loading to true then `setState` of `loading` to false when `async` function stops loading like this.

```
void updateDashboard() async{

    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var api_key = prefs.getString('api_key');
    var userID = prefs.getInt('userID');

    var res = await http.post(('http://myApp.com/getDashboardPreferences/'+userID.toString() + '/' + api_key),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json"
        });

    this.user = User.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));

    setState(() {
      if (res.statusCode == 200) { 
        this.user.setPoints(this.user.points);
      } else {
        print("Something is wrong");
      }

      _loading = false; //Set Loading to false
    });



}
```

Then in your widget build, check for when loading is true and show a progress indicator like this.

```
body: _loading
? Center(
   child: CircularProgressIndicator( //Show a Circular Progress indicator
     valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.cyan),
    ),
  )
:Column(//Show your Dashboard)
```

I hope it helps